# Math.pow(10,6) = 999999.999999 on Doogee DG800 Android phone

Tags: java, double-precision

I know that `Math.pow(10,6)` performs the computation using doubles which means the precision is not absolute. The current release of Google Authenticator uses following code to compute codes:

```
int codeLength = 6;
....
int code = truncatedHash % (int) Math.pow(10, codeLength);
```

Unfortunately at least two Android phones (see [google-authenticator issue 396](https://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/issues/detail?id=396)) compute 999999.9999999, which results in incorrect (not working) authentication codes.

The fix is known and it uses a table of integer dividers as the count is limited to 10 possible values (see the fix referenced from the issue).

And here is the question: Is it the application programmer's fault or the library programmer's fault?  Should the application programmer expect the correct result (1000000) or must the limited precision be taken into account?

Comment: Yes, you have to take limited precision into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a bug in the library, and it should be reported.

Oracle's Javadoc for Math.pow() says, "If both arguments are integers, then the result is exactly equal to the mathematical result of raising the first argument to the power of the second argument if that result can in fact be represented exactly as a double value."

The word "integer" has special meaning here.  A double `x` is an *integer* if `floor(x) == x`.

10.0 is an "integer" by that definition, and so is 6.0, and every integer less than 2^52 can be represented exactly as a double value, so `Math.pow(10.0, 6.0)` should be exactly equal to 1000000.0.

Answer (score 0):

its the "library programmers fault", incorrectly using math-functions is a beginners' mistake and can never be compensated for in wrapping applications - its basic knowledge that operations on floating-points types never yield exact results, relying on these without using proper delta-comparisons with sensible values INTERNALLY is ... very bad.

I recommend switching the library - if it has flaws like this you can be quite sure that there are also a few more, maybe even security-related bugs.

Comment: I guess I misread what you wrote - Where you said "incorrectly using math-functions" it sounded like you were referring to Authenticator's choice to use Math.pow.

Comment: who or what is "Authenticator"?